# How to fill a gap between wall and ceiling?

Tags: walls, sound-proofing, gap

I'm planning to convert an office to a bedroom but need to fill a gap above the door.

Any ideas how I might do this in a way which minimizes sound transfer from living room to inside room, and vice versa?

Looking into office (Click images for larger views):

[image]
[image]

Looking out of office:
    [image]

Comment: What's your plan for the cord running over the wall?

Answer (score 1):

Before you do that, check out how air is getting into and out of that office. That big gap at the top may be there because there is no heating and/or air conditioning register in that room, so its air is just allowed to mix with the rest of that living area via that gap. Closing it up without thinking it through will result in a "dead zone" in terms of air comfort.

Comment: Good catch.  I'd imagine there is register in the room with that big window in there, but the air return may very well be going over the wall.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a few options.

1. Drywall it.  This would involve framing up a small wall above the doorway and then screwing up the drywall and then mudding it.
2. DYI glass pane.  Get a custom size tempered glass pane and put it up into a custom build wood frame.  Trim around it to make it look good.  The thicker the better.
3. Hire a pro to put a glass pane up there.

Comment: A single glass pane is not going to do much for the [sound-proofing] part of this question, nor the air circulation question as raised by *J. Raefield*.  Then again, those *Freedom doors* stop very little sound anyway.